# Error after using \split

Tags: equations, split

i am very very new to latex and i am having problems with this peace of code.
It is compiling, but it spits out dozens of errors called "Missing { inserted. \end{split}"

I guess this means there are some brackets missing? I have copied and altered the code, but i dont understand how the split and & work together.

I want to use it this way, so the equation gets only one reference.

Thank you for helping :-)

```
\begin{equation} \label{Kraftfunktionen}
    \begin{split}
        $\text{Fall CM-A: }$ y &=0.0757x^2 + 0.3912x - 0.0337 \\
        $\text{Fall CM-B: }$ y &=0.1044x^2 + 1.0443x - 1.5213 \\
        $\text{Fall ET-A: }$ y &=0.0521x^2 + 0.1680x + 0.6286 \\
        $\text{Fall ET-B: }$ y &=0.1349x^2 + 2.4139x - 4.0463 
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: remove all the `$` you are already in math mode. (`split` is far more complictated than you need here as it is designed to interact with an outer alignment, I would use the far simpler `aligned`)

Answer (score 3):

The error is caused by the `$` so this runs without error

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{Kraftfunktionen}
    \begin{split}
        \text{Fall CM-A: } y &=0.0757x^2 + 0.3912x - 0.0337 \\
        \text{Fall CM-B: } y &=0.1044x^2 + 1.0443x - 1.5213 \\
        \text{Fall ET-A: } y &=0.0521x^2 + 0.1680x + 0.6286 \\
        \text{Fall ET-B: } y &=0.1349x^2 + 2.4139x - 4.0463 
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

However I'd use `aligned` rather than `split` (in all cases where you do not need to merge the alignment within the split with an outer `align`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{Kraftfunktionen}
    \begin{aligned}
        \text{Fall CM-A: } y &=0.0757x^2 + 0.3912x - 0.0337 \\
        \text{Fall CM-B: } y &=0.1044x^2 + 1.0443x - 1.5213 \\
        \text{Fall ET-A: } y &=0.0521x^2 + 0.1680x + 0.6286 \\
        \text{Fall ET-B: } y &=0.1349x^2 + 2.4139x - 4.0463 
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not quite sure of the meaning here but I suspect that I'd set those text blocks aligned left so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{Kraftfunktionen}
    \begin{aligned}
        &\text{Fall CM-A: }& y &=0.0757x^2 + 0.3912x - 0.0337 \\
        &\text{Fall CM-B: }& y &=0.1044x^2 + 1.0443x - 1.5213 \\
        &\text{Fall ET-A: }& y &=0.0521x^2 + 0.1680x + 0.6286 \\
        &\text{Fall ET-B: }& y &=0.1349x^2 + 2.4139x - 4.0463 
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! This is definetely looking better! Another short question, because i dont want to open a new thread for it..... i am having a reference and placed a dot after it, which doesnt show up?

....Flächen in Abbildung \ref{PATHPLOT_VERLAUF_UEBERSICHT_ANHAND_CM}.

Comment: You'd need to ask in a new thread. The . will show up unless you have some error somewhere that's causing some unexpected expansions `\ref` only has one argument so won't even see that `.`. @PhilMac'Lee